# react ui generator for graphql - apollo

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo, apollo-server

Does it exist a tool (or a combination of libraries) to generate react pages/components according to a graphql schema?!

Something that is able explore the schema to generate a simple page with a table where the graphql query returns a list (possibly, a table with edit/delete button linked to a simple page with form to edit/modify the selected element).
Simple CRUD pages in other words!

Something able to generate a sort of menu based on the relations described in the schema.

If doesn't exist something readymade, any suggestion about how to automate the creation of some ui parts.

Opensource or commercial

Comment: gatsby + source plugin (data link to some headless CMS) can generate content .. but edits usually is on content sourcing CMS (WP, contentful, many more) ... but you can always create own content editor (working with CMS using API) ... all edits need rebuild/redeploy (common for all static site generators)